# ADO.NET - DataTable / Issue when Removing a column that has been previously renamed

Tags: datatable, ado.net

I'm running into an issue while trying to remove a column from a DataTable, when this column has been previously created and renamed from same DataTable.

Here is the code snipnet. I'm using .NET Frameword 4.5.

It is pretty simple to reproduce.

```
try
{
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    data.CaseSensitive = false;

    data.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));

    DataRow newRow = data.NewRow();
    newRow["column1"] = "AAAAA";
    newRow["column2"] = "BBBBB";
    newRow["column3"] = "CCCCC";
    data.Rows.Add(newRow);

    data.AcceptChanges();

    // Rename first column
    Console.WriteLine("Rename [column1] to [COLUMN1] ...");
    data.Columns["column1"].ColumnName = "COLUMN1";
    data.AcceptChanges();

    // Delete Column
    Console.WriteLine("Delete column [column1] ...");
    if (data.Columns.Contains("column1"))
    {
        data.Columns.Remove("column1");
        data.AcceptChanges();
        // Somehow the column will still partially exists after the 2 above lines
        // If you look at the DataTable, it is gone, but if you test existance of the column, it will still think it is there
        if (data.Columns.Contains("column1"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[column1] still Exists! WHY?");
        }
    }

    // Then i need to Recreate that same column ... of course it will fail
    Console.WriteLine("Recreate column [column1] ...");
    data.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string)); 
    // this throw Exception as the data seems to still somehow exists in the DataTable
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error=" + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I add AcceptChanges call almost everywhere to see if it makes a difference but no diff.

Any idea?
Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any comments/help

Comment: very interesting ... only happens after you renamed the column to the original name in upper case ... you can even access the "removed" column with: DataColumn col = data.Columns["column1"]; ... looks like a .net bug to me ...